# Client-side authentication with emberjs and device in Rails4

Tags: devise, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4

Working with user resources is an essential part of every application an so there it's a task which should be automated as much as possible. 
As for Ember I found a tutorial https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-rails-demo/wiki
which describes how it can communicate with devise-based authentication system. And, wow, it's a hell of a boilerplate:)
Have something changed with new devise for Rails4 or things are the same?

Answer (score 2):

[`ember-auth`](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/) dev here.

---

**Edit / Update** for googlers: I have now built a `rails 4` app, with `devise`, `ember`, and `ember-auth`. Apart from the following two gotchas, everything is working fine.

1. `devise` `>= 3.1` *removed* the `tokenAuthenticatable` module. So I'd declare in my `Gemfile`:

   ```
   gem 'devise', '>= 3.0', '< 3.1'
   ```
2. `ember-data` is drifting *away* from `ActiveModelSerializers`, towards [json-api](http://jsonapi.org). Problem is, `json-api` itself isn't even stable. The quick and easy fix is to replace `DS.RESTAdapter` with `DS.ActiveModelAdapter`, which follows the `ActiveModelSerializers` conventions. It should "just work".

So, yeah, `ember-auth` does support `rails4`, because there is nothing BC-breaking with it *per se*.

---

(Previous answer:)

I have no experience with `rails 4`, but [`ember-auth`](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/) itself doesn't rely on `rails 3`, or in fact `rails` / `devise` in particular. The only expectation is a set of API that your server exposes.[1] The [docs](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/docs) describe the expectation from the server API.

As for using rails as a backend, `ember-data` explicitly declares support (and adherence to) [`active_model_seriailzers`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), which provides convenience methods for churning out `json` responses from `rails` models. However, since authentication actions do not conform to the "standard" `REST`ful model responses, the `ember-auth-rails-demo` tutorial itself hand-crafts the expected responses. Example:

```
def create
  # ...
  data = {
    user_id: resource.id,
    auth_token: resource.authentication_token,
  }
  if params[:remember]
    resource.remember_me!
    data[:remember_token] = remember_token(resource)
  end
  render json: data, status: 201
end
```

So, for `rails 4` compatibility, I would investigate more on `devise` compatibility, any `ActiveRecord` changes, and in general other gem compatibilities as needed. As for [`ember-auth`](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/), it will still be handcrafting the expected responses, as outlined in the [docs](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/docs).

[1]: Even this expectation would be customizable, by writing customized `adapters`. Advanced usage, but I can elaborate more on this if needed.

Comment: Update: added `rails4` experience.